# a parameter before self-invoking javascript function

Tags: javascript

I know about self-invoking JavaScript functions made famous by jQuery:
 `( function(x){ console.log(x);})('Hello World');`  logs Hello World.

I recently came across a code where the author uses 0 within the main parentheses and before the function.

example:

```
(0, function(x){ console.log(x);})('Hello World');
```

This will work and log 'Hello World' but I was curious to know what is point of the parameter (in this case 0) before the function? what is the use case for it?

In the case i saw the function was in variable:

```
f = function(x){ console.log(x);};
 (0, f)('Hello World');
```

Comment: It's not a parameter. It's the comma operator at work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator. The actual code might have been something like `(0, foo.bar)(...)`. This is done to make `this` inside `foo.bar` *not* refer to `foo`.

Comment: Than you Flix!  It might be long story but wondering what makes  `this`  in `foo.bar` in this expression `(0, foo.bar)(...) ` not point to `foo`?

Comment: Quentin, can you please post the link to duplicate question?

Comment: Quentin, Never mind. I see the link